# Passing JList value from JFrame to JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog

I'm currently building an application and it has a `JFrame` and a `JDialog`. The `JFrame` has a `JList` called:

`JList lstMainVenuesEvents = new JList();`

And I'm trying to get the value of lstMainVenuesEvents by using:

`lstMainVenuesEvents.getSelectedIndex();`

I can get the value perfectly fine on my `JFrame`, but how do I pass it to my `JDialog`? I thought about creating a setter method in one of my class files and then just getting that value from my `JDialog` file, but surely there's an easy way? Is it possible to just have a method of some sort that passes the data from the `JFrame` to the `JDialog` like a POST request in PHP?

Apologies if I've missed anything crucial out.

Update: here's the code for my JList and JDialog show.

```
JList lstMainVenuesEvents = new JList();
    lstMainVenuesEvents
            .addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
                public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                    // stop from firing twice
                    if (e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                        EventModify evtWindow = new EventModify();
                        evtWindow.setVisible(true);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: I don't know PHP, but wouldn't POST be a similar concept to a setter??

Comment: I'm guessing so. I just presumed there would have been an easier/more efficient way.

Comment: You could pass it as value to the constructor of the dialog, but it depends on what it is you are trying to achieve...

Comment: Hmm I guess so. Would I have to overload the constructor to do that? I'm trying to pass the list value so that I can query the database for a particular value in the list.

Comment: Yes, you'd have to provide a constructor that could take the value from the frame.

Comment: Okay, thanks for confirming.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  BTW - *"how do I pass it to my `JDialog`?"*  Indicates to me that the custom class extends dialog.  Don't extend one, just keep a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't be confident it's "right" but an inversion of control sort of approach usually reduces passing values around.

Assuming the value `lstMainVenuesEvents.getSelectedIndex()` is used on a particular action/event in the `JDialog` you could set an `ActionListener` from the `JFrame`.

```
// some where in the JFrame
jDialog.setButtonPressed(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
    {
        // lstMainVenuesEvents.getSelectedIndex() is accessible in this block
        // put code logic here where
    }
});
```

Comment: My JFrame is the one that holds the lstMainVenuesEvents, so surely this wouldn't be accessible from my JDialog?

Comment: @Xiy This answer assumes you have a class that extends JFrame and that class has a `jDialog` variable which is a reference to the dialog that needs to know the value from the list. If so, the code in this answer can be put in your JFrame class. Of course, this is only helpful if you need it when a button is clicked in the dialog. If you need it when the dialog is created, you can use HoverCraft's suggestion.

Comment: @Code-Guru I'm needing it for when the dialog is created. I can't seem to see HoverCraft's suggestion?

Comment: @Xiy Sorry, I mean MadProgrammer

Comment: @Code-Guru I did try that, but I seem to be getting: "Cannot refer to a non-final variable lstMainVenuesEvents inside an inner class defined in a different method" and when I do make it final, I just get a null pointer exception.

Comment: @Xiy Please edit your question to show your current code and indicate which line gives the NPE.

Comment: @Code-Guru I got it working with MadProgrammer's solution which is basically what I was doing before. The error was being caused by Eclipse defining a variable twice.